# Payment cannot be processed because don't have secure connection.SSL certificate

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, http, https

Estou usando ionic 3 com o plugin do mercadoPago e quando eu vou concluir a compra ele me retorna esse erro, tudo leva em conta a ser um erro causado por o Ionic rodar em uma webView.

`ionic info`(*Caso alguém necessite*)

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.8.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.2, (and 9 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/Pettrin/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
   NodeJS            : v8.11.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 2.15.12
   OS                : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode             : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
*ng:///IonicModule/AlertCmp.ngfactory.js:201 ERROR Error: Your payment cannot be processed because the website contains credit card data and is not using a secure connection.SSL certificate is required to operate.
    at i (mercadopago.js:616)
    at n (mercadopago.js:626)
    at mercadopago.js:585
    at mercadopago.js:480
    at mercadopago.js:444
    at n (mercadopago.js:248)
    at n (mercadopago.js:254)
    at Object.l.getPaymentMethod (mercadopago.js:275)
    at d (mercadopago.js:427)
    at mercadopago.js:479*
```

Dei um `unminify` e editei o arquivo `js`, porem o erro persiste.
Esse [JS](http://yourjavascript.com/0391822072/mercadopago.js) é o modificado, já [esse](https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js) é o original.

**Observação**

Mesmo no modo de produção o erro ainda persiste.

Comment: Olá, coloque o log de erro na pergunta, mas sem ser imagem.

Comment: Olá, editei a pergunta :)!

Comment: Olá, qual a API do MercadoPago que você está usando? Pelo erro parece que você está usando a API Web deles mas deveria ser a de Android: https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/pt/guides/payments/mobile-checkout/receive-payments/ https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/pt/guides/payments/mobile-checkout/introduction/

Answer (score 1):

Se o problema for realmente do SSL voce pode usar o [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org) para gerar um [root SSL](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-root-certificate/)

Gere um key RSA-2048 e guarde no ficheiro *rootCA.key*, este ficheiro vai ser usado para criar o certificado

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 2048
```

Voce pode usar a key que gerou para criar um certificado novo, guarde o ficheiro com o nome *rootCA.pem* este certificado ira ter uma validade de 1024 dias mas pode mudar para qualquer numero que queira

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
```

[image: terminal screen openSSL]

Antes de usar a sua nova certificação tem que dizer ao seu Mac para confiar no seu certificado

Abra Keychain Access no seu Mac e abra a categoria de certificadosno system keychain, uma vez la, importe o ficheiro *rootCA.pem* usando File > Import Items, duplo clique no certificado importado e mude o *When using this certificate* dropdown para *Always trust* na categoria de confianca (trust)

O seu certificado devera ser parecido com isto
[image: keyaccess root certificate]

O seu certificado root pode agora ser usado em localhost, crie um novo ficheiro de configuração OpenSSL *server.csr.cnf* para que possa importar estas configurações quando criando um sertificado em vez de no terminal

```
    [req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
C=US
ST=RandomState
L=RandomCity
O=RandomOrganization
OU=RandomOrganizationUnit
emailAddress=hello@example.com
CN = localhost
```

Crie um ficheiro *v3.ext* para criar um certificado *X509 v3*

```
    authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

Crie uma chave de certificação para o localhost usando as configurações guardadas em *server.csr.cnf*, esta chave ira ser guardada em *server.key*

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -config <( cat server.csr.cnf )
```

Um pedido para assinar o certificado ira ser enviado pelo Root SSL que criamos ainda a pouco para o localhost, o output do certificado estra localizado no seguinte ficheiro *server.crt*

```
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
```

[image: root ssl]

Esta agora pronto para mudar o protocolo do localhost de *http* para *https*, mova a *server.key* e *server.crt* numa localizacao do seu "servidor" para quando o comecar

Numa express app escrito em node.js, esta aqui como devera ser, use isto apenas em localhost não em produção, nome do ficheiro: *dev-server.js*

```
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')
var express = require('express')
var https = require('https')

var certOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('build/cert/server.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('build/cert/server.crt'))
}

var app = express()

var server = https.createServer(certOptions, app).listen(443)
```

Case meu tutorial nao tenha sido muito claro, esta aqui a [source](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec)